# Upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04 with back up

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, reinstall

I would like to re install Ubuntu because I have major  problems with the currently installed 16.04 (it will not update). I want to go straight to 20.04
Please help by describing;

1. How I back up what is on my computer now ?
2. How i install the 20.01 ?
3. How i re install the backed up data?

When describing the steps please do not assume any knowledge of how ubuntu works. Please be as patronizing and simplistic as possible - i will not get annoyed!
Most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

```
1- How I back up what is on my computer now ?
```

Making a backup is just copying your folders/data to an external disk in case the upgrade goes wrong.

```
2- How i install the 20.01 ?
```

There is no release 20.01. Only 20.04 is now available and all what you have to do is copy&paste the commands recommended here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa

```
3- How i re install the backed up data?
```

If everything goes smooth, your data will be save and you don t have to care about anything else.